# Permission to read another app's data?

Tags: android, security

Is there a permission to allow one app to read the (private) data/data//files/... files of another application? If not, how do backup programs like MyBackup work?

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a permission to allow one app
>   to read the (private)
>   data/data//files/... files of another
>   application?

No.

> If not, how do backup programs like
>   MyBackup work?

They backup and restore only things with public APIs. That includes some data from the operating system and some things from applications specifically [integrated](http://www.rerware.com/MyBackup/integration.html) with them.

Answer (score 2):

On a side-note, in the unlikely event that you're the one who's writing both applications, you can make them share the same sandbox by signing them the same way.